# Data preprocessing for custom dataset in pytorch (transform.Normalize)

Tags: python, dataset, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch and CNN. I am kind of confused about Data Preprocessing. Not sure how to go about transform.Normalising the dataset (in essence how do you calculate mean and std v for your custom dataset ?)

I am loading my data using ImageFolder. The images are of different sizes.

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(size=224),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),  transforms.Normalize((?), (?))
                                       ])
train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='roota/',
                                     transform=train_transforms)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're planning to train your network from scratch, you can calculate your dataset's statistics. The statistics of the dataset are calculated beforehand. You can use the `ImageFolder` to loop through the images to calculate the dataset statistics. For example, pseudo code -

```
for inputs, labels in dataloaders:
    # Calculate mean and std dev 
    # save for later processing
```

Typically, CNNs are pretrained with other larger datasets, such as Imagenet, primarily to reduce the training time. If you are using a pretrained network, you can use the mean and std dev of the original dataset for your training.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.  I can calculate mean and std of an actual set of numbers. Not sure how this is done with images or tensors. Do you perhaps have a peace of code or link (just as an example) where you've actually done that ?